# Split character by more than 1 words

Tags: regex, string, r, split

I have the following character:

```
endvotes <- "Yes106No85EH2NT6ES0P1"
```

I'd like to get a `data.frame`looking like this

```
    Yes    No   EH   NT   ES  P
    106    85   2    6    0   1
```

I know how to split each one of those, for example like this:

```
yes <- unlist(str_split(end_votes, "\\No"))[1]
yes <- as.integer(unlist(str_split(yes, "Yes"))[2])

yes
[1] 106
```

I guess one possibility would be to split by positions, but the numbers (one, two or three digits) are not always the same, therefore I'd like to split by the answers (yes, no, etc.). Of course I could do this for every answer (as above) but I'm sure there is a more elegant way. 
Can anyone tell me how this is done nicely?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
endvotes <- "Yes106No85EH2NT6ES0P1"

names <- strsplit(endvotes, "[[:digit:]]+")[[1]]
numbers <- strsplit(endvotes, "[[:alpha:]]+")[[1]][-1]

setNames(as.data.frame(t(as.numeric(numbers))), names)
#  Yes No EH NT ES P
#1 106 85  2  6  0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use regex at all. Try this function from `stringi` package which splits character vector by character classes (like number, letters on punctuation):

```
require(stringi)
stri_split_charclass(str=endvotes,"\\p{N}",omit_empty=T)[[1]]
## [1] "Yes" "No"  "EH"  "NT"  "ES"  "P"  
stri_split_charclass(str=endvotes,"\\p{L}",omit_empty=T)[[1]]
## [1] "106" "85"  "2"   "6"   "0"   "1"
```

`str` is just vector, `\p{N}` and `\p{L}` are classes by which you want to split (N means numbers, L means letters). `omit_empty` to remove "" - empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use a regex like this one, and each match will have the text in the first capturing group, value in the second:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)
```

Basically this selects a string of letters, followed by a string of digits. The parenthesis are capturing groups, that will allow you to retrieve the values you want easily.

See [Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/bT5kZ3)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `regex` too..

```
strsplit(endvotes, split = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", perl = T)
## [[1]]
##  [1] "Yes" "106" "No"  "85"  "EH"  "2"   "NT"  "6"   "ES"  "0"   "P"   "1"  
##
```

To get desired format

```
S <- strsplit(endvotes, split = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", perl = T)[[1]]
res <- data.frame(t(S[seq_along(S)%%2 == 0]))
names(res) <- t(S[seq_along(S)%%2 == 1])
res
##   Yes No EH NT ES P
## 1 106 85  2  6  0 1
```

**OR**

```
res <- data.frame(t(regmatches(endvotes, gregexpr("[0-9]+", endvotes))[[1]]))
names(res) <- t(regmatches(endvotes, gregexpr("[A-Za-z]+", endvotes))[[1]])
res
##   Yes No EH NT ES P
## 1 106 85  2  6  0 1
```